# IBM Worklight - Build failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My environments are failing to build after restart, cleaning, exiting the eclipse, deleting native folders, also I am looking for a reason and perfect fix of this below error as any developer wont be deleting every time when this issue arises, please help

```
error log 


windowsphone build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Error while reading XML file: /Users/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/windowsphone/native/Properties/WMAppManifest.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/windowsphone/native/Properties/WMAppManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
[2013-07-30 17:39:20] FWLST1040E: ipad build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Problem reading info.plist file /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/ipad/native/testLogintestIpad-Info.plist (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/ipad/native/testLogintestIpad-Info.plist (No such file or directory)
[2013-07-30 17:39:21] FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Problem reading info.plist file /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/iphone/native/testLogintestIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/iphone/native/testLogintestIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory)
[2013-07-30 17:39:21] FWLST1040E: windows8 build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Error while reading XML file: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/windows8/native/package.appxmanifest (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/windows8/native/package.appxmanifest (No such file or directory)
[2013-07-30 17:39:23] FWLST1040E: android build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Error while reading XML file: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
[2013-07-30 17:39:24]             A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to read project description file from location '/Users/test/Desktop/16th July/30thJuly-Map/test_Login/apps/test/android/native/.project'.
```

Thanks
djrecker

Comment: I assume this is Worklight 6 on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error in my eclipse after changing the project name by using `Refactor->Rename`
The below fix is for iPhone environment. You can try the same for other environment also.

- The error says it cant find the info.plist file.Try to move to that location in your computer and see wether the file is there or not.
  in your case `ESILoginESIIphone-Info.plist`
- if you cant find the file. just see the `***-Info.plist` in the same path and note down the `****`
  worklight will always append your porject name twice in info.plist file ( dont know why). For example if you have project name as ESI then your plist file name would be ESIESI-Info.plist.

i guess in your project file you have changed the name to `ESILogin`

- Try to rename the project with `****` which you found in above step.

Thats all.
Happy Building.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please look in the Error Log view in Eclipse; there should be an exception trace there which could help us in identifying the root cause.
2. Can you reproduce this? Does it happen only when you create a new project and add all Mobile environments at once, or even when you add only one Mobile environment?
3. What is your Worklight version?

Comment: "once in a while"? this contradicts what you wrote in the question. Please edit the question and better clarify

Comment: I meant this happens randomly, cant reproduce as we dont know the reason. we change our workspace and stuff to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bin folder contents in your project and restart the server.
Deploy all the adapters and application again