# Maximo Anywhere WorkManager build failed

Tags: android, maximo

I am try to build android apps but while creating apps my build failed with **following errors**.

> D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\build.xml:87: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line:
>   D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:720: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:716: Failed
>   building application:
>   com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildException:
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory
>   D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\apps\WorkApproval\android\native\assets\www\default\dojo\cldr\nls\zh-hans-mo.
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)

Comment: Are you running the builder with Admin privileges? The error says "Unable to delete directory" which points to a file permissions issue possibly?

Comment: I have admin privileges.

Comment: Look at the lines mentioned in the xml files and see if there's anything near the xml lines that would indicate a directory to erase and review the security settings. Are you a local user with administrator role or a domain user?

Comment: Did you read the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946676/ibm-worklight-build-failed

Comment: Yes, I am not sure if this is the same error. I got error first time than build successful in second attempt.

Comment: [echo]     environments="common,android,iphone"
     [echo]     nativeProjectPrefix="AnywhereWorkManager"
     [echo]     skinBuildExtensions="build-dojo.xml"
     [echo]     outputFolder="D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager/bin"/>
     [echo]      
     [echo] Worklight Ant Task version 6.1.0.02.20150113-1831
[app-builder] Mar 19, 2015 2:44:51 PM com.worklight.builder.sourcemanager.handlers.android.AndroidManifestSourceHandler checkBuildTarget

Comment: [app-builder] WARNING: FWLST1119W: Android build will fail because the API level used to compile the project is not supported by the Worklight Studio.

[app-builder] It is recommended to use Android API level 18 which is the latest API level supported by the Worklight Studio. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 18, configure your project to build with API level 18 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.
-build-app:  duration 1 minute 14 seconds
  [antcall] Exiting D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\anywhere-apps-builder.xml.

Comment: Says to update your Android SDK

Comment: I tried with API Level 19 and I got same error. Looks like that file created temporary and try to delete during apps build but not able to delete. The file is exist.

Comment: I informed IBM but they didn't see this error before. I tried APT Level 18 and 19 but no luck

Comment: build failed during this line execute in aywhere-apps-builder.xml
 <app-builder
         worklightserverhost="${resolved.worklight.server.url}"
         applicationFolder="${application.home}"
         environments="common,${worklight.envsToDeploy}"
         nativeProjectPrefix="${project.name}"
         skinBuildExtensions="build-dojo.xml"
         outputFolder="${basedir}/bin"/>

Comment: I tried last evening and build ran successfully. But after 5 min I started again and got failed with same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer might seem obvious, but if you have any of the files mentioned in the failure (D:\ibm\AnywhereWorkManager\apps\WorkApproval\android\native\assets\www\default\dojo\cldr\nls\zh-hans-mo)
open ( commandline, eclipse, other editor), this will cause the issue.